# rails 3.2 NoMethodError undefined method `slice' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, slice, nomethoderror

i am getting this error end have no clue how to fix it. the weird thing is, it was working before. i think after i run annotate, it is broken, but not sure.
the error comes from confs.controller index and own methods.
it also rejects something like this: conf.machine_brand[0,1].upcase as NoMethodError [ ] bla bla 
this is my conf model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: confs
#
#  id                 :integer          not null, primary key
#  machine_brand      :string(255)
#  machine_model      :string(255)
#  control_unit_brand :string(255)
#  control_unit_model :string(255)
#  tool_axis_x        :decimal(, )
#  tool_axis_y        :decimal(, )
#  tool_axis_z        :decimal(, )
#  rotary_axis_number :integer
#  linear_axis_number :integer
#  turning_mode       :boolean
#  milling_mode       :boolean
#  description        :text
#  xml                :text
#  user_id            :integer
#  developer_id       :integer
#  created_at         :datetime         not null
#  updated_at         :datetime         not null
#

class Conf < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :linear_axis_number, :control_unit_brand, :control_unit_model, :description, :developer_id, :machine_brand, :machine_model, :milling_mode, :rotary_axis_number, :tool_axis_x, :tool_axis_y, :tool_axis_z, :turning_mode, :user_id, :xml 

   belongs_to :developer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'developer_id'
   belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'

   validates :user_id, presence: true
   validates :developer_id, presence: true
end
```

this is confs.controller:

```
class ConfsController < ApplicationController
before_filter  :signed_in_user, only:[:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter  :developer_user, only: :destroy

def new
  @conf = Conf.new
end

def index
  @grouped = {}
  Conf.all.each do |conf|
    letter = conf.machine_brand.slice(0,1).upcase
    @grouped[letter] ||= []
    @grouped[letter] << conf
end
end

def show
@conf = Conf.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
    format.html #index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @conf }
    format.xml { render xml: @conf }  
  end
end

def own
  @grouped = {}
  Conf.where(:developer_id => current_user.id).each do |conf|
    letter = conf.machine_brand.slice(0,1).upcase
    @grouped[letter] ||= []
    @grouped[letter] << conf
  end
end

def create
@conf = Conf.new(conf_params)

  if @conf.save
    flash[:success] = "New Configuration uploaded!"
    redirect_to conf_show_path
  else
    flash[:error] = "There is a problem!"
    render 'new'
  end
end

def destroy
  @conf = Conf.find(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect_to conf_show_own_path
end

def update
  @conf.update_attributes(params[:conf])  
end

private

def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?
    store_location
    redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in"    
  end
end

def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
end

def developer_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.developer?
end

def conf_params
  params.require(:conf).permit(:xml, :user_id, :developer_id) if params[:conf]
end

end
```

and this is conf.new if you wish:

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Configuration')%>
<h1> Upload new configuration </h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">

     <%= form_for @conf, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :machine_brand %>
    <%= f.text_field :machine_brand %>

    <%= f.label :machine_model %>
    <%= f.text_field :machine_model %>

    <%= f.label :control_unit_brand %>
    <%= f.text_field :control_unit_brand %>

    <%= f.label :control_unit_model %>
    <%= f.text_field :control_unit_model %>

    <%= f.label :tool_axis_x %>
    <%= f.text_field :tool_axis_x %>

    <%= f.label :tool_axis_y %>
    <%= f.text_field :tool_axis_y %>

    <%= f.label :tool_axis_z %>
    <%= f.text_field :tool_axis_z %>

    <%= f.label :rotary_axis_number %>
    <%= f.text_field :rotary_axis_number %>

    <%= f.label :linear_axis_number %>
    <%= f.text_field :linear_axis_number %>

    <%= f.label :turning_mode %>
    <%= f.text_field :turning_mode %>

    <%= f.label :milling_mode %>
    <%= f.text_field :milling_mode %>

    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>

    <%= f.label :xml %>
    <%= f.text_field :xml %>

    <%= f.label :client %>
    <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.where(:admin => false, :developer => false), :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "Select a client"}, :class =>"user" %>

    <%= f.label :me %>
    <%= f.collection_select :developer_id, User.where(:id => current_user.id), :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "Select me"}, :class =>"user" %>

<br />
    <%= f.submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is the line that is causing it `letter = conf.machine_brand.slice(0,1).upcase` then it means that the returned conf.machine_brand is nil and not being set. If it has to be set you will need to have a validation in your model so it cannot be created without a machine brand.

Comment: `conf.machine_brand.slice(0,1)` i think you got the error here as you do not have any association between 'Conf` and `machine_brand` so simply do in your controller `letter = params[:machine_brand].to_s.slice(0,1).upcase` or `letter = params[:conf][:machine_brand].to_s.slice(0,1).upcase`

Comment: I think conf.machine_brand may be empty for certain rows. Check if conf.machine_brand is null in your database. Or in IRC Conf.all

Comment: actually, `Conf.all.group_by{|conf| conf.machine_brand? ? conf.machine_brand[0].upcase : 'N/A' }` should get you exactly what you want

Comment: Also, I don't think you should be using `strong_parameters` with AR mass-assignment protection whitelist on. And you only permit `:xml, :user_id, :developer_id` in your `conf_params` the remaining attributes will simply be nil in your model…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conf.machine_brand.slice(0,1)`
 I think you got the error here `machine_brand` so simply do in your controller
`letter = params[:machine_brand].to_s.slice(0,1).upcase unless params[:machine_brand].blank?`
 or
`letter = params[:conf][:machine_brand].to_s.slice(0,1).upcase unless params[:machine_brand].blank?`

Comment: how does he not have an association between Conf and machine_brand ?  It's in his attr_accessible and it's in his form

Comment: @Althaf look at my post now

Comment: i added all attributes to the conf_param and validated them, so my problem is solved, thank you a lot all of you

Comment: can you please vote up ...@kalahari Thankss...let me vote up your question

Comment: it says i am under 15 rep and cannot vote :( i am new, how reputation increases?

Comment: you can ask several questions and answer the questions will increase your reputation

Answer (score 0):

As @Rajarshi mentioned, the error is in the following code

```
conf.machine_brand.slice(0,1).upcase
```

The error says that you're calling `slice` on a `nil` object, which means that one of your conf records has a nil machine_brand.  I'm not sure how you'd want to approach this problem but this issue will be lessened if you add a validation that requires a machine_brand

```
class Conf < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates :machine_brand, presence: true
```

or you can only fetch for records where `machine_brand` is present

```
Conf.where('machine_brand IS NOT NULL').each do |conf|
  conf.machine_branch.slice(...)
```

Comment: he is sending the machine_brand through parameters look into his view file

Comment: that may be true but that won't prevent conf(s) with null machine_brand to be created by other means.

Comment: @RajarshiDas notice how he has no `:machine_brand` in his `conf_param`

Comment: i added all attributes to the conf_param and validated them, so my problem is solved, thank you a lot all of you